# Install Meteor without disabling Firewall or Defender on Windows

Tags: meteor, chocolatey

I've been trying to [install meteor](https://www.meteor.com/install) but could not. The setup stuck after Exctration of zip files.

[image: powershell error when installing meteor]

I've tried using Powershell and cmd with Administrative privileges.

Is there any installer or package with that I can install meteor with installing [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install)?

OR

Some solution mentioned to disable Windows defender and install meteor. I can't disable windows defender. Is is possible to allow program/port which chocolatey/meteor use while instaling, which I can allow in outboud/Inboud firewall rule?

Comment: Am I right in saying that you had previously installed meteor using a different mechanism? Looks like it is trying to uninstall a previous version, and it is failing. I would suggest manually removing that, and then try the install again.